# Import data from Excel to list in Sharepoint Online site

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

I need to upload data from excel to Sharepoint list in SharePoint online site.

I can extract data from excel but how can i connect to the Sharepoint online site and upload the data progrmatically from a console exe.

Kindly advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I succeeded using SSIS package.

Its easiest way to push and retrieve the data from SharePoint online site.

Download, SharePoint List adapters from below link and install this integration adapter with visual studio BI.

https://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/82369

It provides SharePoint List source and destination tool in the source section of the tool.

Just configure the source and destination with corresponding URL, then the data can be imported or exported in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [SharePoint client object model 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx), you can download the SDK from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=35585)

As how to insert the excel data into SharePoint online list, this [blog](http://alancejacob.blogspot.ca/2012/06/read-data-from-excel-file-and-insert-in.html) post has some code snippet to do it, I did tested it, but I think its logic is correct, you may adjust some parts to fit your needs, also, the code refers to the SharePoint client object model 2010, and current version of SharePoint online is 2013, so there could be some differences.

Comment: Hi Matt, my case im using Sharepoint bpos site. So that how can i authenticate after connecting to the Sharepoint online site.

Comment: You can do it with the SharePoint client object model, check this blog:http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/01/authenticating-net-client-object-model.html